# Saving date in yyyy-MM-dd format into SQL Server 2008 if I passed date in dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am trying to save date into a SQL Server 2008 database. I have converted date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format even though the date stored in database as `yyyy-MM-dd` format. My button click code:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    sample = fdate;
}

public class sample
{
    public string sample(DateTime fdate)
    {
       string qry = "insert into sample values('"+fdate+"')";
       SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(qry);
    }
}
```

Database date(column) datatype is `date`. May I know the reason??
My other classes

```
  public class Connection
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    public SqlDataAdapter ad;
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public void connclose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    public Connection()
    {

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
        cmd = null;
    }
  //------------------ connection string---------------------------------------------------------
  ---------------------//
    public string nonquery(string qry)
    {
        string str;
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

            conn.Open();

        cmd=new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        str=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        conn.Close();
        return str;

    }

    public SqlDataReader query(string qry)
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        conn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return dr;
    }
```

Comment: Just use parameters instead.

Comment: @Dai, It will solve the problem??

Comment: just format it when you read, not save. it is best practice to store date using `yyyy-mm-dd` format to avoid culture conflicts.

Comment: The database stored in SQL Server **doesn't have any format**! It's stored as a binary value ....

Comment: @marc_s, Then why its not saving as per my code format?

Comment: Always use **parameters** for your query - this prevents SQL injection attacks, and it also gets rid of all those messy multiple single quotes, and it also avoids any trouble with date wrongfully stored as strings!

Comment: On top, do not even submit code samples that do not work. I am quite sure that conn has no method query. Not with a small q anyway . And I am quite sure you would not ask for a SqlDataReader on an insert. ExecuteNonQuery is what you look for. Random code will never do waht you want. Especially if it does not even compile.

Comment: @TomTom, Now see my updated question

Comment: @marc_s, I use parameters but no changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Sql Server does **not** store your data in the yyyy-MM-dd format at all. It stores dates in a binary format that's not human readable, and only converts them to the format that you see for convenience in the query tool. If you're thinking about formats, you're already doing something wrong. You need to do it like this:

```
public string sample(DateTime fdate)
{
    string qry = "insert into sample values( @date )";
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here") )
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fdate;

        cn.Open();
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //use dr here...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you have that `conn` object that looks like it has code to help you avoid some of this boilerplate. That's fine, but you will need to update that object so that it's `query()` method requires more than just an sql string. It **must** also have some mechanism to accept parameter data separate from the sql command. Otherwise, you won't just find yourself with date conversion problems like this; you'll also find yourself trying to figure how your database got hacked.

Comment: 1+ for Nice explanation.